# dojox.mobile.currentView is null after moving from one tab to another

Tags: cordova, dojo, dojox.mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using the following tab controls :

```
function tweetsAction()
{
    var w = dojox.mobile.currentView;
    if (w.id != "tweetsView") w.performTransition('tweetsView', 1, "slide", null);
}

function secondAction()
{
    var w = dojox.mobile.currentView;
    if (w.id != "secondView") w.performTransition('secondView', 1, "slide", null);
}

function thirdAction()
{
    var w = dojox.mobile.currentView;
    if (w.id != "thirdView") w.performTransition('thirdView', 1, "slide", null);
}
```

Initialising them in Worklight JavaScript, such as :

```
function initCommonControls()
{
    console.log("Android initCommonControls");

    WL.TabBar.init();
    WL.TabBar.addItem("tweetsView", tweetsAction, "Tweets", {image:"images/icons/help_bw.png", imageSelected:"images/icons/help.png"});
    WL.TabBar.addItem("secondView", secondAction, "Second", {image:"images/icons/help_bw.png", imageSelected:"images/icons/help.png"});
    WL.TabBar.addItem("thirdView", thirdAction, "Third", {image:"images/icons/help_bw.png", imageSelected:"images/icons/help.png"});

    WL.TabBar.setSelectedItem("tweetsView");
}
```

Tabs appear OK on app launch :

[image]

However, when I click on either the second or third tab, both of those move over the first one :

[image]

And I see this JavaScript error in the JS console :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Which means that `var w = dojox.mobile.currentView; is not able to get the current view after moving off the initial tab.

This is what my HTML looks like :

```
<!-- Tweets View -->
    <div id="tweetsView" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" data-dojo-props="selected: true">
        <div class="spacing"></div>
        <h1 id="head0" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" 
            data-dojo-props="label:'Tweet Search', fixed:'top'"></h1>
        <button onclick="getTweets()">Get Tweets</button>
        <input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" id="sampleItem">
        <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeList" id="theTable"
            class="tweetviewList">
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- second View -->
    <div id="secondView" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" data-dojo-props="selected:false">
        <div class="spacing"></div>
        <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" 
            data-dojo-props="label:'second view', fixed:'top'"></h1>
        This is a second view
    </div>

    <!-- third View -->
    <div id="thirdView" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" data-dojo-props="selected:false">
        <div class="spacing"></div>
        <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" 
            data-dojo-props="label:'third view', fixed:'top'"></h1>
        This is a third view
    </div>
```

Any ideas as to why the `dojox.mobile.currentView` is returning nothing after switching a tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that it's related to this: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15040. Sounds like they've removed dojox.mobile.currentView from the latest versions of Dojo Mobile. I'm currently doing some stuff with Worklight and I'm also getting 'undefined' for dojox.mobile.currentView.

There's a couple of recommendations on that page, but it seems everything now needs to be much more complex - yay :(